# How to publish a NuGet package from the prerelease stage to the release stage?

Tags: nuget, release

We publish a set of NuGet packages to a feed. When it comes to release time we want to be able to remove the prerelease versioning of the latest packages and publish them as final releases. I am not sure about the best practice in doing so.

There are a couple schools of thought that we have come up with.

1. Utilize a package like [NugetRepack.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NugetRepack.Tool) to manipulate the generated packages and publish them as a release.
2. Regenerate all of the NuGet packages by building the solution with the release version. Because all of the assemblies are the same as the latest prerelease version we are publishing the exact same packages minus the prerelease on it.